# Zend_Form_Element_Select onchange

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, selectlist

I am unable to set value of text, radio and other form elements based on a select element onchange.
All form elements are part of the same form.
The values to be set are to be fetched from database table without refreshing/redirecting the whole page (may be using Ajax).
Solution should be MVC based. I am a ZF novice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work with the help of following link:
http://zendgeek.blogspot.in/2009/07/ajax-with-json-and-prototype-in-zend.html

I used JQuery $.ajax() in place of prototype.js Ajax.Request() as the latter was conflicting somewhere with a datepicker element and I thought why to include one more js file when already JQuery is there.